# Why is there no DOMRect type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to determine the type of the object returned by `element.getBoundingClientRect()`, which [MDN lists as "DOMRect"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

If I log the object to the console, it's listed as a `DOMRect` with properties: height, width, top, bottom, left, right, x, and y. However, `DOMRect` doesn't exist as a type in TypeScript, from what I can see.

The closest type I could find in TypeScript is `ClientRect`, which is basically the same but lacks the 'x' and 'y' properties.

I also found type `DOMRectInit`, which is a `DOMRect` without top/bottom/left/right.

The problem I had that prompted this question was resolved when I realized that 'x' and 'y' pretty much always mirror the 'left' and 'top' properties, but what's going on here? Why is TypeScript not aligned with the standard browser API?

Also, is it safe to assume that 'x' always equals 'left' and 'y' always equals 'top'?

Comment: Have you only tested with the iOS Safari JavaScript runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript DOM type declarations [originate from this repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator), which seems to be based on some version of DOM as implemented in Microsoft Edge browser, with some changes applied in the build process.

In other words, DOM types could be not up to date with the latest standards and/or other browser implementations. [There is open issue about this process in general](https://github.com/Microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator/issues/101), but if some particular definition is missing, you can always file an issue about that in TypeScript repo.

Comment: Ah, I always forget that TypeScript is developed by Microsoft. Now it all makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer to my second question [in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect):

> [Left] has the same value as x, or x + width if width is negative
>
> [Top] has the same value as y, or y + height if height is negative

So basically, it *is* safe to assume 'x' is the same as 'left' unless 'width' can be negative.